# User Specific Restriction based on Page Visit

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have to implement in a website restriction based on specific user visit. User can visit each page five times in a month after he will require registration to continue visiting the page. if user not registering in this month then in next month also he can visit each page 5 times in month. After that registration pop up will start showing. website is in ASP.NET MVC 5

Thanks

Comment: How are you tracking individual users? You need to use cookie for tracking the visit from a particular client.

Comment: You can track the IP visit count per month and take action according to that count.

Comment: what if he clear cookies and visit again more times? Use server database to track the visiting of user so you can handle it properly. Get IP address and make history table where the user visiting data to be store.

Comment: In mostly cases IP is dynamic which is always changing.